# HTML won't load the image on my web server that I just downloaded from a zip file

Tags: html, linux, file, frontend, image-loading

[web page with my uploaded image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcIR2.png)

I was trying to find the path my computer was using. I tried the basic code that
I learned in a program I'm currently in, but it didn't seem to work. The path is desktop/my-skillcrush-project/101-skillcrush-project-images/images-icons/html-icon.png

The program directed to download the zip file of the image on my computer and create a folder. With the root directory associated with the file including the image.Then to use this code.  <img src="img/html-icon.png" alt="HTML icon"/ (closing tag disappears when I try to type it. Sorry, it's in my code.) and that was it. It seems too simple in my opinion. How should the files be saved so that it will show up??????

Comment: What program are you using to create your file?

Comment: If your html file is in Desktop, no need to specify `desktop/` in the image URL. the image will break then.

Comment: And also, use a dedicated text editor like VS Code or Notepad++, not Chrome DevTools.

Comment: What does the console say? I notice that there is an error there.

Comment: The console probably says "Failed to load resource". Probably because of an invalid image path?

Comment: It turned out the file was in the wrong place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### What is wrong

The problem is, in the `src`, you put a relative path. In HTML, a relative path is a path without a slash(`/`) at the beginning. So, HTML was expecting a folder called desktop in the `101-skillcrush-project-code` folder which had all of the other folders and the image.

### What you should do

You do not need to put the full(absolute) path for the image. You can put the **relative** path. That is, relative to where the index.html is located.

### Solution

So, in the `src` of the image, you can put `101-skillcrush-project-images/image-icons/HTML Icon.png`.

### More Info

[HTML File Paths on W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)
[HTML File Paths on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/)

Comment: Ok didn't work. Any other ideas??
It's not working because of the HTML document.
Where do I put the HTML document to make it relative to the image? I just think that might be the problem. This is for learning purposes so I really appreciate it.

Comment: It is not about moving the HTML file. You should move the **image** so it is in the same folder as the HTML file. And from there on, you just put the name of the image in the `src`.

Comment: Thanks! it turned out the file was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is much easier if you `make a clear structure for all of your html assets`. That also makes it much easier to handle your paths. So for example start with a `root` folder - lets name it html, where you put all your html pages in. Inside html create a sub folder for e.g. for your images and css. Folder structure can look like that:

```
 /html    image path from html folder: <img src="img/html-icon.png">
   |- img    save "html-icon.png" here
   |- css 
   |- js
   |- fonts
   |- etc
```

To access an image from another folder e.g. css folder, `you first have to go one level up` with `..` and then, go into the img folder. e.g. `<img src="../img/html-icon.png">`

If you have your images somewhere outside your "web folder" the paths can get a pain. So just organize your assets - it is much more effective and much easier for you to find and work with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! understanding the structure of it really helped.